# Is there a name for the intersection of the graphs of first and second order reactions?

Tags: kinetics

Is there a name for the point where a first order rate of reaction meets a second order one.
[image: reactant graph]
This point highlighted above.

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.se! I don't really understand your question. The kinetics of a given reaction is fixed. You can not have a first order and a second order kinetics  for the same reaction. Any way, at the point of intersection, the rates of reactions are equal.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there isn't a specific term for that point.

If you have a one-step first order reaction

$$\rm A \xrightarrow{k_1} B + C, \quad \text{rate} = k_1[A]$$

that can run backwards as a second order reaction

$$\rm B + C \xrightarrow{k_{-1}} A, \quad \text{rate} = k_{-1}[B][C]$$

and the rates of those reactions are equal, you can call that point "equilibrium".

You can't really plot the rates separately the way you have unless you have a common concentration, e. g. plot a change in concentration $x$ where $\rm [A] = [A]_0 - x$, $\rm [B] = [B]_0 + x$, and $\rm [C] = [C]_0 + x$.